# Какие разговорные словосочетания употреблять в кавычках, а какие - нет?

Tags: пунктуация, орфография

Например: Свой в доску; большой опыт за плечами; мне это до лампочки / до  фонаря /  до луны (т.е. меня это не волнует); назвал сумму от фонаря (например, при торге) и т.д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все такие словосочетания давно стали обыденными и не заключаются в кавычки. О кавычках можно только при необычности словосочетания. Такие словосочетания давно уже зафиксированы словарями. 
Не берутся также в кавычки следующие словосочетания. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, Серж! А как называются такие словари?

Comment: Обычные толковые словари. На грамоте посмотрите. Там, в словарях,  эти словосочетания  зафиксированы.

Answer (score 1):

Кавычки нужны в случаях, когда применено нестандартное или условное выражение, которое не следует понимать буквально. Это может быть намёк на что-то многим известное из фольклора, недавней рекламы и т.п., но не вошедшее в широкое употребление.

```
Он поскользнулся на обледенелой ступеньке и месяца два ходил на работу с "бриллиантовой" рукой.

Мы с женой "изменили жизнь к лучшему", купив телевизор Philips.
```

В других случаях кавычки могут обозначать скептицизм пишущего по отношению к самому обычному названному понятию:

```
Сестра познакомила меня с одним кандидатом наук. Этот "учёный" и закона Ома толком не знает.
```